# Give a reference to forming object from created object

Tags: java, reference

What is the best way to do the following:

I have a class A, which creates and holds objects from class B. Object of class B is doing his own things, and sometimes he has to call a method of a parent object (of class A). I heard it is not the best idea to hold a reference of object A in object B (Idea is shown in the code snippet).

```
Class A{
    private B objectB;
    public A(){
        objectB = new B(this);
    }
    public void methodA(){
        // [...]
    }
}

Class B{
    private A objectA;
    public B(A objectA){
        this.objectA = objectA;
    }
    public void methodB(){
        // [...] do some stuff
       objectA.methodA();
    }
}
```

Is it really a bad approach to do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: It very much depends on what you're trying to do! But you might want to think about `class B` extending `class A`.

Comment: They are just references, dont worry it will not duplicate your objects if this is your concern.

Comment: I know that, it doesn't really affect the performance, but I just heard that this is not a good way from architectural look.

Comment: consider to use interfaces, ie create interfaces for all methods from A which are used in B, let A implements your interface, and pass to B constructor that Interface as argument. it might sounds messy, but i think it might be better design. but in general, i think your question might be bit broad

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your class B acts like a sort of proxy or decorator with the difference that A and B don't share any common interface. If your design requires class B to act like this (proxy, decorator, ...) the best way is to define a common interface: B implements the A's interface and can "impersonate" it: in these cases, sharing a reference to the "proxyed" class is not bad, it is actually required. E.g.:

```
public interface A {
 void methodA();
}
public class AImpl implements A {
  @Override
  public void methodA() { /* .... */ }
}
public class AProxy implements A {
  private final A a; // Use the interface not the implementation
  public AProxy(final A a)  { this.a = a; }
  @Override
  public void methodA() {
     /* .... */
     a.methodA();
     /* .... */
  }
}
```

The other approach is that you define an hierarchy in which A is the parent of B so B "needs" to know about A to work, or conversely A and B have a 1 to 1 E-R dependency: you can follow a composite design pattern - mostly abused on ORM techniques - or a dependency injection pattern. In ORM techniques parents and children always have a reference of each other but they act independently from each other.

```
// It might be an @Entity
public class A {
   private B child;
   /* setter and getter */
}

// It might be an @Entity
public class B {
   private A parent;
   /* setter and getter */
}
```

In dependency injection you have the options to enforce this relationship using a class with a private final field and its constructor parameter (more or less as you did) or using a private field and its setter.

```
public interface A {
 void methodA();
}

public class AImpl implements A {
  @Override
  void methodA() { /* .... */ }
}

public class B { // B does not implement A!
  private final A a; // Use the interface not the implementation
  public B(final A a) { this.a = a; }
  public void methodB() { /* ... */ }
}
```

or

```
public class B { // B does not implement A!
  private A a; // Use the interface not the implementation and it is not final
  /* setter and getter */
}
```

It is not a matter of whether it is bad or not to share a reference of a parent/external object, but it depends on what your design requires for and you have to model your application accordingly. In my first example B implements A's interface, B *acts* like A while in the latter B does not implement A's interface and *depends on* A: there's subtle but important difference.